# Ssl jdbc connection in Adobe ColdFusion 2016 w/4096 cert

Tags: ssl, jdbc, coldfusion

I am updating an existing jdbc connection which uses SSL to point to a new server. To do this I need to load a new certificate. That process appeared to go fine. Yet when updating the connection details all I get is “connection failed”.

The original connection utilized a 1024 strength cert, and had no issues. I believe I have eliminated everything but CzF and here’s whu ... after installing the cert I set up DBeaver to use the CF runtime (and thus the same keystore, etc) and with the SAME connection parameters could connect to the new database NO PROBLEM!

My belief is it is the 4096 strength that is throwing CF off.

Has anyone encountered anything like this or have any suggestions?

The platform is:
Adobe ColdFusion 2016
IIS 8.5
Windows Server 2012 R2

All have the latest patches/updates as of the time of this posting.

Thanks for any thoughts!
Forrest

Comment: Apparently this was reported as a bug.  https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204087